# Modalpopup windows appears after the whole function is processed

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager, modal-popup

I have a modal popup window that I want displayed at the start of the function. Instead, it appears after the function has been processed.

```
    protected void RadListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string script = "function f(){$find(\"" + DisclaimerAlertWindow.ClientID + "\").show(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, true);  


// other business logic
}
```

How can I get the modalpopup to be displayed when the function is called?

Comment: That code runs on the _server_.  You need to use Javascript before the postback.

Comment: How would I use JavaScript before the postback, given this is a Telerik Listview control?

Comment: They should have client-side Javascript events.